# How to import only the rows that meet the conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query is:

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM 
    (SELECT
         ig_idx,
         --, count(ig_root) over(partition by ig_root) AS GameCount1
         ig_root,
         ig_game_type,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ig_root
                            ORDER BY CASE WHEN ig_game_type IN ('12', '1x2') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, ig_game_type ASC) AS seqnum
     FROM 
         Info_Game) AS t
ORDER BY 
    ig_root, seqnum
```

Result :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/124e0/1/0)

SQL Server 2014 table schema

```
CREATE TABLE Info_Game
(
    [ig_idx] int, 
    [GameCount1] int, 
    [ig_root] int, 
    [ig_game_type] varchar(5), 
    [old_seqnum] int
);

INSERT INTO Info_Game ([ig_idx], [GameCount1], [ig_root], [ig_game_type], [old_seqnum])
VALUES (1, 3, 11, '12', 1),
       (2, 3, 11, 'ah', 2),
       (3, 3, 11, 'ou', 3),
       (4, 1, 12, '12', 1),
       (5, 4, 13, '1h_ah', 1), 
       (6, 4, 13, '2h_ou', 2),
       (7, 4, 13, 'ah', 3),
       (8, 4, 13, 'ou', 4),
       (9, 4, 13, '1h_ou', 5),
       (10, 5, 14, '1x2', 1),
       (11, 5, 14, '1h_ah', 2),
       (12, 5, 14, 'h', 3),
       (13, 5, 14, 'ou', 4),
       (14, 5, 14, '1h_ou', 5);
```

Only `ig_root` with seqnum of 1 and `ig_game_type` of '12' or '1x2' .

I want to get  ig_root of the same number

I want the result

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ec3fb/1/0)

SQL Server 2014 Schema

```
CREATE TABLE Info_Game
(
    [ig_idx] int, 
    [GameCount1] int, 
    [ig_root] int, 
    [ig_game_type] varchar(5), 
    [old_seqnum] int
);

INSERT INTO Info_Game ([ig_idx], [GameCount1], [ig_root], [ig_game_type], [old_seqnum])
VALUES (1, 3, 11, '12', 1),
       (2, 3, 11, 'ah', 2),
       (3, 3, 11, 'ou', 3),
       (4, 1, 12, '12', 1),
       (10, 5, 14, '1x2', 1),
       (11, 5, 14, '1h_ah', 2),
       (12, 5, 14, 'h', 3),
       (13, 5, 14, 'ou', 4),
       (14, 5, 14, '1h_ou', 5);
```

Of the same number of ig_root, seqnum = 1 and type = '12' or type = '1x2'
I want to get it ig_root of same number

```
ig_idx  ig_root ig_game_type  seqnum
1       11      12            1
2       11      ah            2
3       11      ou            3
4       12      12            1
5       13      1h_ah         1  <--- this 
9       13      1h_ou         2
6       13      2h_ou         3
7       13      ah            4
8       13      ou            5
10      14      1x2           1
11      14      1h_ah         2
14      14      1h_ou         3
12      14      h             4
13      14      ou            5
```

idx 5 : This means that seqnum is 1, 
but the type is not 12 or 1x2. 
So I do not want to bring ig_root  number 13.

like this:

```
ig_idx  ig_root ig_game_type  seqnum
1       11      12            1
2       11      ah            2
3       11      ou            3
4       12      12            1
10      14      1x2           1
11      14      1h_ah         2
14      14      1h_ou         3
12      14      h             4
13      14      ou            5
```

Comment: Please provide sample output...conditions are not clear

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: just edit with current result & ur required result.

Comment: Is prior question complete now? This can be indicated by "accepting" (I see you have not done this on any question so far) Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46759314/sql-minimum-value-i-do-not-want-to-get-results-that-do-not-fit-in-the-conditi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with cte as (
      SELECT
          *
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ig_root ORDER BY ig_idx) AS seqnum
      FROM Info_Game
)
select ig1.*
from Info_Game ig1
where exists (
        select *
        from cte ig2
        where ig2.ig_root = ig1.ig_root
            and ig2.ig_game_type in ('12', '1x2')
            and ig2.seqnum = 1
    )
```

This returns all rows from Info_Game for which a row exists that has both a ig_game_type of '12' or '1x2' and is the first row of all rows with the same ig_root value. The definition for 'first' was not clear to me from your question, so I have taken the liberty to use ig_idx for the ordering.
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/124e0/7)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to output (or retain) some of those rows, then use a `WHERE clause` such as the one below:

```
SELECT
      t.*
FROM (
      SELECT
            ig_idx
            --, count(ig_root) over(partition by ig_root) AS GameCount1
          , ig_root
          , ig_game_type
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ig_root
                              ORDER BY CASE WHEN ig_game_type IN ('12', '1x2') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                              , ig_game_type ASC
                              ) AS seqnum
      FROM Info_Game
      ) AS t
WHERE t.seqnum in (1,2)
ORDER BY ig_root, seqnum
;
```

> Only ig_root with seqnum of 1 and ig_game_type of '12' or '1x2'

As I don't understand that completely these are some **alternatives** for that `WHERE clause`:

```
WHERE t.seqnum = 1

WHERE ig_game_type n('12','1x2')
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to decode your question, but from what I udnerstand, you want to get few rows from the query you've posted. So simply use `where` clause ie `WHERE  ig_game_type in('12','1x2') and seqnum = 1` like this :

```
SELECT
      t.*
FROM (
      SELECT
            ig_idx
            --, count(ig_root) over(partition by ig_root) AS GameCount1
          , ig_root
          , ig_game_type
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ig_root
                              ORDER BY CASE WHEN ig_game_type IN ('12', '1x2') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                              , ig_game_type ASC
                              ) AS seqnum
      FROM #Info_Game
      ) AS t
WHERE  ig_game_type in('12','1x2') and seqnum = 1
ORDER BY ig_root, seqnum
```